# Cmake (GUI) can't find libpng present in msys64

Tags: build, cmake, libpng, msys

I am pretty new to msys64 and cmake. Currently I am trying to build inkscape by using cmake-GUI and msys64 on windows 10. I am getting annoying error about "FindPNG" can't find libpng. I have libpng inside /c/msys64/mingw64/lib folder but I don't understand how do I tell cmake from GUI to go in that folder and fetch libpng? Also I am unclear about what path I should provide for PNG_DIR? I have googled but I couldn't find any thread that solves problem while keeping msys64 under consideration. I have attached a snapshot of my cmake for further clarity.

[image: CMAKE]

Comment: Set `PNG_DIR` to `/c/msys64/mingw64` and try again.

Comment: Still it is giving the same error

Comment: I'm uncertain how the packing for msys64 goes, but in general, it is common for there to be separate runtime and development packages for libraries.  Are you sure you have the *development* components for libpng installed?

Comment: I solved the issue by building my project from msys mingw64 shell. I don't understand why cmake GUI was unable to do that.

Comment: Wait, were you running the CMake GUI of a ***Windows*** CMake install?  You would definitely want to be running the msys64 `cmake`, whether in command-line or GUI mode.